# Capture Fingerprint and save as image on my pc

Tags: fingerprint

I'm working on a project and i need to collect biometric data like fingerprints, I would like to know if there's any windows app out there that can work with my Digital persona fingerprint scanner to save scanned prints as jpg files on my computer.

I'd appreciated the help.